# Battery drains a lot after iOS11 update

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 7 used to consume 3-4%  of battery in standby mode but after upgrading, it is consuming 40-45%  of battery in 10 hours of standby mode. What shall I do?

Comment: It's fairly common for OS updates to reset your preferences in certain areas, particularly where the new OS does a major feature-add in the area that preference applies, or where it gives or removes finer control of options.   So you have to go back through your settings and make sure they are what you want.

Answer (score 10):

You are not alone (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ios11+drains+battery), and usually this happens with all major iOS upgrades. Besides following the usual steps to reduce battery usage the probably only course of action is to wait for iOS updates.

Comment: This is really painful

Comment: Some people wait for the 1st or 2nd update before installing the major upgrade : did this with Unix updates and saved hours of hassle....

Comment: Password Encryption software like MP-1 also not working with iOS11. Have to downgrade to iOS10 till the point all fixes are not available